# Why are power sets called power sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, intuition

Why are power sets called power sets? What is so powerful about them?

Comment: Well, for a finite set of $n$ elements, its power set has $2^n$ elements - which is a *power* expression.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Personally I'd call $2^n$ an *exponential* expression (or rather function), and $n^2, n^3,$ etc. power expressions. So why is the power set not called the exponential set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a set A with $|A|=N$, we have $|\wp(A)|=2^N$, 2 to the *power* of $N$.

That lead to the name power set.

The notation $2^N$ came from the fact that this was the case when $A$ is finite.

---

In German, a *Potenzfunktion* is a fuction in the form of $X^n$. The name *Potenzmenge* (power set) appears to come form *Untersuchungen über die Grundlagen der Mengenlehre* (1908) by Ernst Zermelo. For example, in 1906, Gerhard Hessenberg used the name *Menge der Teilmengen*, i.e. set of subsets.

The German word *Potenz* comes form the Latin word *potentia*, which means power in English, and was used in different contexts, e.g. in politics and philosophy, but also in mathematics. So it probably was a combination of the fact what I mentioned above and that the power set is bigger, so more powerful.

Comment: Wow, hadn't thought about that...

Comment: I disagree that that is the sole reason for the notation $2^N$, as when considering $2=\{0,1\}$ and $A^B$ is the set of functions from $B$ into $A$, then $2^A$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(A)$.  I don't know the historicity of the notation, but at least today I don't think your reason captures all the underlying connections.

Comment: @Hayden You were right, I edited the post.